Connecting with Case Studies Prior to Publication
I submitted an article for publication quite a while ago that was a “Discussion Article” for a performing arts/theatre journal. I previously worked as a Resident Dramaturg for a documentary theatre company, and I use my time as an employee at the company to provide an example of the ethical quandaries one confronts when trying to dramatize the lives of real characters who may or may not have been queer and who died 100 years ago.
I use an example of a show that has been in development at the company since 2017. I give proper credit in the article to the theatre company, the team, and the artistic director specifically. Now that the article has been chosen for publication, it was recommended that I share the article with the artistic director of the company to ensure I am presenting them accurately. The work I discuss in the article is technically still in development, but it has had 2 staged readings with ticketed audiences. In the article, I only share the research that I conducted, and even that research could be accessed by the general public (I was an independent researcher with no academic affiliation when I conducted the research, so I know this for a fact).
Is it unethical for me to share this company’s process in the making of this work? I have a meeting scheduled with the artistic director to discuss the article, and I expect given he would like a discussion that he likely doesn’t want anything published. Am I jumping to conclusions too much regarding this?

I think this is quite a tricky situation. Presumably your employer did not know you were using your employment as a research project. Might that violate your employment agreement? Research with human subjects often requires prior ethics approval - how much have your conversations with others influenced the work? Finally, by crediting the team and company you may falsely create the impression that they endorse the work - that seems to be the journal's most pressing concern. Overall it kind of sounds like you tried to sneak something through which doesn't give a good impression.

Your title says "connecting"; do you mean "contacting"?

Jumping to conclusions about what, exactly? His wants?

Is this related to academia?

This is a theatre company, so not an academic research project. All research was independent and didn’t go through ethics approvals as it’s not attached to an institution. I also did not have a contract of employment, as I started at the company as an intern and was given an official title in name only, even though I was the only person on the team performing my job role.
